# Optimizar consulta MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Tengo una consulta que me tarda 0.2650 seg en ejecutar y querría optimizarla, he realizado bastantes pruebas (Añadir nuevos indices, eliminarlos, crear views) pero nada ha mejorado el rendimiento de la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT enlace_click.id,enlace_click.enlace,enlace_click.cantidad
FROM enlace_click
INNER JOIN enlace ON enlace_click.enlace = enlace.id
ORDER BY enlace_click.cantidad ASC , enlace_click.enlace DESC

Mostrando filas 0 - 29 (total de 802430, La consulta tardó 0.2650 seg)
```

EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type table type          possible_keys       key      key_len  ref                                  rows    Extra    
1   SIMPLE            enlace_click  ALL UNIQUE,enlace   NULL     NULL     NULL                                 1074631 Using filesort
1   SIMPLE            enlace        eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY   4       gnula_serie.enlace_click.enlace      1       Using index
```

**Buscando por que puede llegar a tardar tanto:**

```
SELECT enlace_click.id,enlace_click.enlace,enlace_click.cantidad
FROM enlace_click
INNER JOIN enlace ON enlace_click.enlace = enlace.id
ORDER BY enlace_click.cantidad ASC , enlace_click.enlace ASC

Mostrando filas 0 - 29 (total de 802430, La consulta tardó 0.0016 seg)
```

EXPLAIN:

```
 id select_type table   type            possible_keys       key     key_len ref                             rows    Extra   
 1  SIMPLE              enlace_click    ALL UNIQUE,enlace   NULL    NULL    NULL                            1074631 Using filesort
 1  SIMPLE              enlace          eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY 4       gnula_serie.enlace_click.enlace 1       Using index


SELECT enlace_click.id,enlace_click.enlace,enlace_click.cantidad
FROM enlace_click
INNER JOIN enlace ON enlace_click.enlace = enlace.id

Mostrando filas 0 - 29 (total de 802489, La consulta tardó 0.0009 seg)
```

EXPLAIN:

```
 id select_type   table           type    possible_keys     key       key_len   ref                               rows     Extra    
1   SIMPLE        enlace_click    ALL     UNIQUE,enlace     NULL      NULL      NULL                              1074670  NULL
1   SIMPLE        enlace          eq_ref  PRIMARY           PRIMARY   4         gnula_serie.enlace_click.enlace   1        Using index
```

INDICE:

```
Nombre de la clave  Tipo    Único   Empaquetado Columna     Cardinalidad    Cotejamiento    Nulo
cantidad,enlace     BTREE   No      No          cantidad    2023            A               No
                                                enlace      1074590         A               No
```

Comment: Hola Strings, bienvenid@. la parte de  "Buscando por que puede llegar a tardar tanto:" es la respuesta a tu primera parte?. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b Buenos días, ahí es donde intento encontrar la solución por eso mismo edito la sentencia original(1ª) para ver porque tarda tanto en ejecutar la sentencia. Saludos!

Comment: Ah, veo que la que te tarda `0.0009 seg` es porque quitas el `Order by`... realmente el tiempo original de `0.2650 seg` es *poco*... tanto te interesa optimizarla?

Comment: @lois6b Si, Si quisiera mostrar los 20 primeros registros de esa consulta (Limit 0,20) sería un tiempo muy elevado 0.2s para la pagina. Saludos

Comment: 800mil registro son bastantes; el procesarlos para mostrarlos igual es tiempo; imprime el tiempo (Horas, minuto, segundos y si se puede milesimas de segundos) en que inicias la consultas; otro cuando termina, otro cuando empiezas a processar/mostrar y otro al finalizar el procesamiento para que veas donde se tarda más. Por cierto los valores que pones de "0.XXX s" es menos de un segundo.

Comment: Creo que la principal pregunta es por que necesitas tanta optimización. Los 0.27 seg esta muy bien considerando que esta haciendo `INNER JOIN`  y `ORDER BY` adicionalmente. Considerando que estos deben mapearse y ordenarse casi 1 millón de registro, no se que mas quieres conseguir.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo al resultado de `EXPLAIN` que se muestra el problema principal está al momento de ordenar los registros.  La manera de optimizar esta consulta es crear un índice en la tabla `enlace_click` que contenga las columnas: `(cantidad, enlace)`.  Es importante que el orden en el que aparecen las columnas en la definición del índice sea el mismo que el que se utiliza en la cláusula `ORDER BY`, en este caso aparece primero `cantidad` y luego `enlace`.

Por otra parte:

- ¿Es necesario hacer la intersección (`inner join`) con la tabla `enlace`? Ya que en la proyección (`select`) no hay campos de la tabla `enlace`.
- ¿Puede haber registros en la tabla `enlace_click` con valores en la columna `enlace` que no existen en la tabla `enlace`?